# Squid: Bus Error with transparent SSL Proxy

Tags: ssl, proxy, transparent, squid

I try to configure squid (running on openwrt) to act as transparent proxy for ssl connections. While "normal" non-ecrypted connections work fine squid always crashes when i try to run it with ssl connection.

My Configuration for that looks like this:

```
https_port 3129 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/opt/ssl/ssl.pem key=/opt/ssl/ssl.pem              
ssl_bump server-first all
```

But everytime i try to start squid i got just one line of error:

```
Bus error
```

I am using Squid 3.5.2-2 and the debug log looks like this:

```
2015/12/02 17:28:42.021| Initializing https proxy context
2015/12/02 17:28:42.026| support.cc(1068) method: Using SSLv2/SSLv3.
2015/12/02 17:28:42.029| support.cc(1200) sslCreateClientContext: Setting RSA key generation callback.
2015/12/02 17:28:42.029| support.cc(1204) sslCreateClientContext: NOTICE: Peer certificates are not verified for validity!
2015/12/02 17:28:42.030| support.cc(1211) sslCreateClientContext: Setting CA certificate locations.
2015/12/02 17:28:42.030| Initializing https_port [::]:3129 SSL context
2015/12/02 17:28:42.030| Using certificate in /opt/ssl/ssl.pem
2015/12/02 17:28:42.034| support.cc(1714) readSslX509CertificatesChain: Certificate is self-signed, will not be chained
2015/12/02 17:28:42.093| support.cc(1533) contextMethod: Using SSLv2/SSLv3.
2015/12/02 17:28:42.096| support.cc(855) configureSslContext: Setting RSA key generation callback.
2015/12/02 17:28:42.098| support.cc(858) configureSslContext: Setting CA certificate locations.
2015/12/02 17:28:42.100| support.cc(901) configureSslContext: Not requiring any client certificates
2015/12/02 17:28:42.101| tools.cc(543) leave_suid: leave_suid: PID 6477 called
2015/12/02 17:28:42.103| tools.cc(565) leave_suid: leave_suid: PID 6477 giving up root, becoming 'nobody'
2015/12/02 17:28:42.106| debug.cc(403) parseOptions: command-line -X overrides: ALL,1
Bus error
```

So my question now is: Why istn't squid even starting? What is causing the bus error?

Comment: I encountered the exact same problem (same squid version running on an openwrt router as well). Have you come up with a solution?

Comment: as far as i know the system can not handle squid with ssl due to a lack of performance on the running system... i tried it on my router but it does not have enough memory and/or cpu power. it causes other processes to crash and that will lead to a bus error... some devices are not  designed to run it... maybe you should run it on another more powerful device and just redirect your traffic to it... that worked for me

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure it's a space left issue, try to reduce the size of your dynamic certificates :

```
dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=1MB
```

this option in your Squid config file will be useful too:

```
sslproxy_session_cache_size 500 KB
```

If you still got *Bus error*, install *strace* with *opkg* and give a try with Squid. You will get more logs on what happening.

Comment: well no. It seems that squid is just to demanding on resources to run it on my old TP-Link Router... Installing additional packages would make it just worse...